# "we do not want to overstate our welcome"

Tags: meaning, grammar, eggcorn

> **"we do not want to overstate our welcome"**

meaning

"we **DO VERY MUCH** welcome you!"

OR

“we'd better keep our message of welcome at **a moderate level**”？

as in this context

> each season, more people are watching the show, more awards
>
> more attention, the reviews continued to be wonderful
>
> and I think that's part of why Vince was like “hey we do not want to
>   overstate our welcome”

Answer (score 11):

I think it should be **overstay**.

"We do not want to overstay our welcome" means "We do not want to stay longer than our hosts wish us to stay"

Answer (score 1):

> We do not want to **overstate** our welcome

First, you need to figure out who the welcoming party is and who is receiving the welcome.

In this case, I believe the audience is the welcoming party and the party receiving the welcome are the speaker and their compatriots.

This phrase is similar to

> We do not wish to **overstay** our welcome

but with a different meaning.

Usually, I hear the phrase within its fuller context, for example,

> We do not want to **overstate** our welcome, but we would like to thank everyone who enjoy our show and made us the Number One country music radio station.

It would mean,

> We are not exaggerating, because we don't want you to feel we are exaggerating that we are very much appreciated by you the listeners of our show.